# Is thread sleep necessary when reading from a socket stream?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, io

I am reading from a socket input stream like this

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
String line;

while((line = in.readLine()) != null){
   // do something
   Thread.sleep(10); // for example 10ms
}
```

Now, [the read method of an input stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29) blocks until data is available.

In this case is *cooling-down* the thread a good idea? After 10ms it will be blocking anyway.

Please do not tell me about non-blocking IO, I know about that.

I am just curious whether it helps performance/CPU in anyway.

Comment: Why do you think it *might* help performance?

Comment: If the input stream is non-blocking then that is important information you should include in the question.

Comment: Its not a blocking input stream, @Raedwald I thought it might have an impact on os thread scheduling as shem mentioned.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No**. There's no reason to sleep. Why artificially slow down the read loop? Let it read data as fast as it comes in.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to let other threads a cpu time, you should use:

```
Thread.yield();
```

But I'm not think it's necessary here- let the system thread scheduling do its job- it's pretty good.